# Insert JavaScript code from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

i need gets a html code by jsonp like method, and display this on a div element. This works with simple html like an images, text, etc. But now the code can content a JavaScript tags and need insert this on a div, but the javascript, don't runs, i resume it with a example:

```
var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');

div.innerHTML = '<scipt type="text/javascript"> console.log('I run!'); </script>';
```

this don't works, too i probe:

```
var otherdiv = document.createElement('div');

otherdiv.innerHTML = '<scipt type="text/javascript"> console.log('I run!'); </script>';

div.appendChild(otherdiv);
```

But don't works too.

How I can insert the code in away that the JavaScript runs?

Comment: It should be `<script>`, not `<scipt>` (missing an R), and it'll have to be inserted into the live dom, not just dangling in nowhereland.

Comment: in your second snippet, make 'I run!' to "I run!" and it'll work.

Comment: You misspelled "script" and the quotes in your console.log are breaking up the string.

Comment: Ok ok sorry, i make a simple example on the fly, the real code is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to extract all JavaScript and `eval` it.

You can extract JavaScript with a regular expressions like:

```
var match = html.match(new RegExp("<script[^>]*>(.+)</script>"));
console.log(match);
```

This is a far from optimal way of executing JavaScript, very error prone and possibly unsafe. I would strongly advise against it.

Comment: If is the only way :-(, this is a problem if the script have a document.write... I'm apply the code but it is dinamyc, i don't know the code before insert. The only way is replace /document.write[\s\t\n\r]*\((.*)\)/ patterns by theParent.innerHTML(\1);

Comment: `document.write` is obscenely horrible.

Comment: Yeh, but i don't decide wath insert

Answer (score 0):

You should use a script loader like LAB, yep/nope, or [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js). The browser has built-in restrictions, script loading is the best practice for including scripts on a page.

You also would have to escape the single quotes.

```
console.log(\'I run!\');
```